# HTTP 415 unsupported media type Using Spring MVC Restful Web Services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Java8 to build restful web services, But I am unable to perform Post request due to following error:

**The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.**

Here is my controller Class

```
@RestController
public class SpringRestWebService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmployee(@RequestBody final Employee employee)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Here is the POM file which includes jackson library for JSON parsing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inov8</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenRestWebServices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.0</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Model Class: Employee

```
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public Employee(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Note: I am including application/json as content-type in request header, Moreover I am able to perform Get request successfully and the problem is only with POST request.**

**Postman Request**

[image: Web Service Request Body]
[image: Web Service Request Header]

I have tried every option available over the internet,But still I am facing the error.

Comment: We'll need some more information on the client-side. How are you creating your request? Do you have any client-side code?

Comment: I am hitting the service using Postman

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing your Postman request?

Comment: if you pass the request body in raw mode, change the text to json

Comment: Dear @masoudvali It is already set to JSON.

Comment: @Simon, I have edited the Post to include postman screenshots

Comment: What's in the params tab?

Comment: Could you add the Employee class ?

Comment: do you set RestWebServices as prefix for your endpoint?

Comment: @JEY I have included the Employee class.

Comment: @masoudvali There is nothing in Param Tab. I have not added any query parameter.

Comment: Can you check from your postman code, if content-type is being set correctly? The code button is below the `Send` button. It would be helpful if you post that

Comment: POST /RestWebServices/employee? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "id":"100",
 "name":"xyz"
}

Comment: Test your api with a curl request. if it works then the problem is at the postman. If that doesn't work, the problem is with your spring configuration. Most probably it looks like a problem in configuring spring, as you're are not using starters dependencies.

Comment: @JawadTariq maybe this guide will help you https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ to compare steps.

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove `consumes="application/json"`? I don't recommend this as a solution, merely to pinpoint the root cause.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I am able to resolve ths issue. Kindly check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me appreciate Stak overflow community for helping me. After investigating the issue in detail, I come to know that **Http 415 Unsupported Media Type** was due to missing **`<annotation-driven/>`** in my servlet.xml.After adding this I am able to get rid of this error.

Moreover if you ever face similar error,you can visit below link to get it rectified.

https://inneka.com/programming/ajax/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc/